# Weird jQuery/JS error: if I place script before the controls load i get 0x800a138f; if I put it after I get 0x800a1391

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

Ok, I would really appreciate help on this. I have been struggling with this for almost a week now and it is really frustrating... I have an AjaxModalPopup on my master page and it works fine on all browsers, but I need it to work on IE9 specifically. These are the errors:

If I place the script BEFORE the controls load: 
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'show' of undefined or null reference

If I place the script AFTER the controls load: 
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'ShowModalPopup' is undefined

Below is the code to my master page (the script in question is directly below the ModalPopupExtender control 'ShowModalPopup()' and 'HideModalPopup()'):

```
<%@ Master Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Site.Master.vb" Inherits="Site" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>.:: CSI GROUP ::.</title>
<meta name="keywords" content="HTML5,CSS3,JavaScript" />
<link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="icon" href="Images/Otros/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/Otros/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<script src="Scripts/AvisoPrivacidad.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/CambiosPaginaPrincipal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/CambiosContenido.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="Form1" runat="server">
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</ajax:ToolkitScriptManager>   
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="mpeSeleccion" BehaviorID="mpe" runat="server" TargetControlID="lnkDummy"
PopupControlID="Panel1" DropShadow="True" BackgroundCssClass="FondoAplicacion">
</ajax:ModalPopupExtender>

<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowModalPopup() {
$find("mpe").show();
return false;
}
function HideModalPopup() {
$find("mpe").hide();
return false;
}
</script>

<!-- HEADER -->
<div class="header">      
<!-- BOTON LOGIN -->     
<div class="loginDisplay">
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="LOGIN" OnClientClick="return ShowModalPopup()" />
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDummy" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Label ID="LoggedInDisplay" runat="server" Width="200" Visible="False" />
<asp:Button ID="LogoutButton" CssClass="button" runat="server" Text="LOGOUT" Visible="False" />
</div>
<!-- FIN BOTON LOGIN -->

<!-- IMPLEMENTACION DEL SLIDESHOW -->
<asp:Image ID="SlideshowImages" CssClass="page" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Slideshow/Slide1.jpg" />
<ajax:SlideShowExtender ID="SlideShowExtender1" runat="server" AutoPlay="true" BehaviorId=""
Loop="true" TargetControlID="SlideshowImages" SlideShowServicePath="Slideshow.asmx" 
SlideShowServiceMethod="GetSlides" PlayInterval="10000">
</ajax:SlideShowExtender> 
<!-- FIN IMPLEMENTACION DEL SLIDESHOW -->

<!-- CONTENIDO DE CADA PAGINA INDIVIDUAL -->
<div id="mainContainer" class="main" style="display:none;">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
</div>
<!-- FIN CONTENIDO DE CADA PAGINA INDIVIDUAL -->
</asp:Panel>

<!-- IMPLEMENTACION DEL LOGIN -->
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="CajaDialogo" style="display:none;">
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton9" CssClass="closeButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/Otros/background.png" OnClientClick="return HideModalPopup()" />
<div>
<iframe src="Login.aspx/#LOGINFRAME" class="LoginFrame" />
</div>
</asp:Panel>
<!-- FIN IMPLEMENTACION DEL LOGIN -->

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I added the AjaxControlToolkit tag on my web.config, so the prefix is what it should be.

I thank you all in advance and hope that you can help me.

Comment: By the way, this is not the entire file, so please omit the open/close tags of my .net controls

Comment: I'd lose one of the jQuery script tags for a start.

Comment: Thanks, but it made no difference :/.

Answer (score 0):

`$.find(...)` is a jQuery function.

You're missing a dot `.` after the `$` in `$find`.

**Update**

Just realised you're using the AjaxControlToolkit and this is wrong. Sorry

Comment: Hmmm I tried it but now it won't actually show the popup. I tried using $("form").find("mpe").show();

Comment: What HTML actually gets rendered in the browser.

Comment: [output file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j8xt312kjat1zlo/output.html) this is the output file